# PHP / HTML select and unselect links to change URL

Tags: php, html

I have this code where i show different status names:

```
$request = $_GET;
$array = Statuses('Porting', $behavior='');
foreach($array["results"] as $ret) {
    $sql="SELECT * from orders_porting where status = '".$ret["name"]."' ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

    if($_GET[$ret["name"]] == '1') {
        unset($request[$ret["name"]]);
        $query = http_build_query($request);
        echo '<a href="?'.$query.'">';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="?'.$query.'&'.$ret["name"].'=1">';
    }
    echo '<div class="TicketsMenuTabs""';
    if($_GET[$ret["name"]] == '1') {
        echo ' id="active"';
    }
    echo '>'.$ret["name"].' ('.mysql_num_rows($rs).')</div></a>';
}
```

it shows 'buttons' that can be clicked and i want to be able to un click them too.

i have added the `unset` and `http_build_query` in the if statement, but if 2 buttons are selected and i click on one of them again to un selected it, they all become un selected

Comment: first of all, don't use mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop, if every link is selected, you will have unset everything when you reach the end (of your loop).

try this:

- after unseting the link in your $request variable, do the output and reset the $request variable with the content from $_GET.
- don't forget to set the $query variable (see the anwer from Mickael)

so it should look something like this:

```
$request = $_GET;
$array = Statuses('Porting', $behavior='');
foreach($array["results"] as $ret) {
    $sql="SELECT * from orders_porting where status = '".$ret["name"]."' ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

    if($_GET[$ret["name"]] == '1') {
        unset($request[$ret["name"]]);
        $query = http_build_query($request);
        $request = $_GET;
        echo '<a href="?'.$query.'">';
    } else {
        $query = http_build_query($request);
        echo '<a href="?'.$query.'&'.$ret["name"].'=1">';
    }
    echo '<div class="TicketsMenuTabs""';
    if($_GET[$ret["name"]] == '1') {
        echo ' id="active"';
    }
    echo '>'.$ret["name"].' ('.mysql_num_rows($rs).')</div></a>';
}
```

also - try to check if the key in $_GET exists before reading it - like this:

```
$request = $_GET;
$array = Statuses('Porting', $behavior='');
foreach($array["results"] as $ret) {
    $sql="SELECT * from orders_porting where status = '".$ret["name"]."' ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

    if(isset($_GET[$ret["name"]]) && $_GET[$ret["name"]] == '1') {
        unset($request[$ret["name"]]);
        $query = http_build_query($request);
        $request = $_GET;
        echo '<a href="?'.$query.'">';
    } else {
        $query = http_build_query($request);
        echo '<a href="?'.$query.'&'.$ret["name"].'=1">';
    }
    echo '<div class="TicketsMenuTabs""';
    if(isset($_GET[$ret["name"]]) && $_GET[$ret["name"]] == '1') {
        echo ' id="active"';
    }
    echo '>'.$ret["name"].' ('.mysql_num_rows($rs).')</div></a>';
}
```

and last but not least - i'll have to agree with krzysiej's comment - don't use the mysql_* functions - they are [depricated](http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php) - use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) or pdo-mysql instead (sorry - can't post more that two links because of my rep - you'll find the link to pdo-mysql if you click the "depricated" link)

Answer (score 0):

In the else section of your condition `if($_GET[$ret["name"]] == '1')` the variable `$query` isn't set because you set it here :

```
if($_GET[$ret["name"]] == '1') {
    unset($request[$ret["name"]]);
    $query = http_build_query($request);
    echo '<a href="?'.$query.'">';
}
```

Try this :

```
$query = http_build_query($request);

if($_GET[$ret["name"]] == '1') {
    unset($request[$ret["name"]]);
    echo '<a href="?'.$query.'">';
} else {
    echo '<a href="?'.$query.'&'.$ret["name"].'=1">';
}
```